# Android how to load Image file with different extension using Picasso

Tags: android, image, picasso

This is a different situation. I want to load a image file which has stored with different extension like **'photo.xyz'**  instead of **'photo.jpg or photo.png'** using Picasso. to avoid  image from gallery i am storing image like this. Please help me is there any option to show like this.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Neither Picasso nor Android (which does the actual image decoding) cares what the file name is. It can be anything. The type of the image is always determined from the first few bytes of the actual image data.

Answer (score 0):

As a small workaround you can programmatically put .nomedia file into your app folder to prevent images to be cached by mediaserver and displayed in a Gallery app.